# Django не подключаются стили css

Tags: python, django

Начала изучать django  и столкнулась с такой проблемой: не подключаются стили css. Просматривая код элемента - стили не применяются. Документацию читала.

index.html

```
 {% load static %}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'main.css' %}" />

    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="general-container">
     <div class="container top-container">
          <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                    <h1 class="title"> Наш магазин скоро откроется</h1>
                     <h1 class="title"> Оставляйте ваш емайл</h1>

               </div>
              <div  class=" col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4"  >
                        <form action="" method="post" class="form-inline text-center"> {% csrf_token %}
                             <div class="form-group">
                                 <label>Ваш email: </label>
                                 <input name="{{ form.email.name }}" class="form-control">
                             </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                 <label>Ваше имя: </label>
                                 <input name="{{ form.name.name }}" class="form-control">
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn-primary">Отправить </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
              </div>
          </div>
     </div>

    </div>

     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

style.css

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;

}

.top-container{
    padding-top: 10%;
}

.general-container{

    background-color: #dc5129;
    height: 100%;
}

.general-container form{
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.general-container form label{
    font-weight: 100;
    color: white;
}

.btn-orange{
    background-color: #e8643e;
    border: none;
}

.btn-orange:hover{
    background-color: #dc5129;
    border: none;
}

.title{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

Кусок кода setting.py

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'static'

TEMPLATES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'))
STATIC_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'))
```

Comment: Вы подключаете `main.css`, а приводите в примере стили из `style.css`. Может перепутали названия?

Comment: В index.hrml не подключен style.css